# How to delete firebase user account if the user singn up with phone number using android firebase auth ui?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

The below code works for deleting the user account when the user signup with google, but not sure how to handle if the user is signup with phone number.

```
val currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser ?: return

val credential: AuthCredential? = when (currentUser.providerData[1].providerId) {
    "google.com" -> {

        val fireBaseContext = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().app.applicationContext
        val googleAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(fireBaseContext)
        GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleAccount?.idToken, null)
    }
    "phone" -> {

        // How to get the below params(verificationId, code), when we use firebase auth ui?
        PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(currentUser.phoneNumber!!, "")
    }
    else -> return
}

currentUser.reauthenticate(credential!!)
    .addOnCompleteListener { reAuthTask ->

        if (reAuthTask.isSuccessful) {

            AuthUI.getInstance().delete(this)
                .addOnFailureListener { deleteTask ->

                    view.showSnackbar(deleteTask.message!!)
                }
        } else { //Handle the exception

            view.showSnackbar(reAuthTask.exception?.message!!)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using below method you can delete the current user.

```
FirebaseUser currentUser= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
currentUser.delete()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "User account deleted.");
                }
            }
        });
```

[Learn more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#delete_a_user)

You can delete user using the cloud function, just pass user uid to it.

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
.then(function() {
    console.log("Successfully deleted user");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
});
```

Comment: It needs re-authentication, otherwise the delete method will fail. Please check the documentation - "To delete a user, the user must have signed in recently. See Re-authenticate a user." - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Comment: yeah it needs re authentication, so whats the matter?

Comment: Please go through my code carefully, in case of google authentication I got the credentials without prompting the user to sign-in again.

Comment: You need to delete the user using cloud function then no else case.

Comment: Is there any possibility to get the credentials, if the user login with phone?, like how we got for google using val googleAccount = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(fireBaseContext)
        GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(googleAccount?.idToken, null)

Comment: No, you can get credential only by sign in process as you can see the same is being done in reauth and for phoneauth there's no method other than cloud.

Comment: Thankyou so much for the information. Then I will prompt the user to enter sms code before deleting the account. I guess this is best practice.

Comment: welcome, but it wont be good approach. I'll prefer creating cloud function its way easier and better approach.